# How can I find out if my question has been asked before?

Tags: feature-request, duplicates

When I ask a question I do get a list of related questions that helps a lot to find out if my question has been asked before.

However I sometimes find an additional question that covers exactly the same topic in the list of related questions that only appears on the right after having posted the question. To avoid dupes I then need to delete my question.

It would be a nice feature to see this list at a time point before posting a question. This could also help new users to avoid posting dupes.

Comment: Can you provide any example? Probably just a shortcoming in the related questions retrieving capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same related questions now appear when you're composing a question (in fact, this was done only a few hours after you posted this question).

- The “questions with similar titles” shown under the title when composing the question are based only on the title.
- The “similar questions” shown in the sidebar once you've entered enough of a question body are the same you'd see in the sidebar under “Related” after posting.

For more details, see [Feedback requested: Similar Questions displayed in sidebar on /ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91568/feedback-requested-similar-questions-displayed-in-sidebar-on-ask).

Comment: I've only just now noticed this change, brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

A search in the search bar, and examining posts with tags through the tags section related to your question should be a good way to check for duplicates. Also google searches should turn up results from AskUbuntu.